# Using ReplaceChild in HtmlAgilityPack in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to convert HTML to markdown in a windows store app. The following code works in a .NET 4 MVC project

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html); 

foreach (var x in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//strong"))
{
    x.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("**" + x.InnerHtml + "**"),
    x);
}
```

`SelectNodes` is not available in the WinRT build so when porting the code I replaced this with Descendants.

```
foreach (var x in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("//strong"))
{
    x.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("**" + x.InnerHtml + "**"),
    x);
}
```

This code leaves the HtmlDocument unchanged. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Descendants` expects an element name, not an `XPath`, therefore your code doesn't return any element and document remains unchanged.

You need to remove *slashes*:

```
foreach (var x in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("strong"))
```

Comment: that was it. I'm getting another issue now but I'll save it for a separate thread. Thanks!